# get_the_post_thumbnail adds garbage when class is added

Tags: wordpress

**WordPress 5.3.2**

I try this:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post, $attr=array( 'class' => 'logo_of_site_where_quote_published' ))
```

And I get this:

```
<img src="http://ved/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/twitter.svg" class="attachment-logo_of_site_where_quote_published size-logo_of_site_where_quote_published wp-post-image" alt="Twitter logo (svg)" />
```

Well, the result is littered. I'd like to have just class=logo_of_site_where_quote_published. Could you give me a piece of advice:

- Is there an elegant and wordpressyc solution to get the desired tag?
- Should I use what is offered? That is
  attachment-logo_of_site_where_quote_published class.

Comment: Great it works..please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `get_the_post_thumbnail` function which takes **post id** as first parameter, **size** as second parameter and **attributes** as third. If you are not using any parameter you can replace that with blank (''). As you are sending an array in 2nd param, it has been taken as size and adding prefix as per the WordPress.

I tried your code and recitified a little and it start working as you expected :

```
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'', $attr=array( 'class' => 'logo_of_site_where_quote_published' )); ?>
```

I just passed second parameter as blank to the function. 
It will work for you. Please check and let me know.